# React Native Firebase - I keep having a version mismatch error even I already updated the version of Firebase module

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase module in my React Native project. The current version I am using is `v6.2.0`. I accidentally installed `v6.3.4` of `@react-native-firebase/crashlytics`, and it threw this error:

I already performed these steps in my attempt to fix it:

1. npm uninstall @react-native-firebase/crashlytics
2. Android -> Build -> Clean Project
3. Android -> Build -> Rebuild Project
4. npm install @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@6.2.0 --save
5. Restart metro bundler
6. Reinstalled app through npx react-native run-android
7. I checked package.json and package-lock.json. The versions are already updated to 6.2.0

After doing the steps above, it still keeps on throwing the error below. Am I missing anything in these steps?

[image]

Comment: did you try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm-install again?

Comment: npm start -- --reset-cache fixed this issue